# Radians : negative and positive values

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Recently I have been reading books on DSP where I came across Polar co-ordinates. I understand that on Polar graph (4 quadrants) we have $0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3}{2\pi}$ and $2 \pi$ radians as we move from one quadrant to another. But further on they refer values in between $-\pi$ to $\pi$ values?

Which quadrant / range or rather what values represents $-\pi$ to $\pi$ - Like $-\pi < \omega < \pi$ ?

[image]

Comment: Negative angle means: go clockwise.

Comment: So does -pi to pi range means starting from 180 degree then going clockwise back again to 180 degree as shown in above picture?

Comment: If you start from 180 degrees at $-\pi$, then you go anticlockwise reaching $270° \hat{=} -90°$ at $-\pi/2$, and finally $180°$ at $\pi$. An angle of $\alpha < 0$ means you go $r\cdot \lvert\alpha\rvert$ far in the clockwise orientation starting from $0$. So $-\frac{5\pi}{6}$ for example takes you to the same point as $\frac{7\pi}{6}$. Every angle $\varphi$ corresponds to $\varphi + 2\pi k,\; k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not so good in maths - I understand @DanielFischer is stating but in simple terms from where we have to start and until where travelling clockwise would mean range -pi to pi?

Comment: Going clockwise around the circle means the angle decreases. Going anti-clockwise means the angle increases. So if you go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, you go around the circle anti-clockwise, but you start on the left, not on the right, where the angle is $0$. If you're going from $0$ to $-\pi$, then you're going clockwise half around the circle.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer I get the point you have mentioned - in such case −π to π would mean starting from 180 degree going anti-clockwise to full circle back again to 180 degree. Thanks once again for all your explanation